# ddsmoothmenu on loading page

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem with ddsmoothmenu: While the page is loading, two items of the menu seem to be expanded so the menu height is bigger than what it should be.

Once the page is loaded, the menu is displayed well. 
I've tried to use defer to delay the execution but it doesn't seem to work, another option I'm considering is to hide the menu till the webpage is fully loaded.

Is there any solution to fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you share your demo code

Answer (score 2):

In that case you can try **setTimeout**

`setTimeout(function () {
 *Call your function here*
 }, 3000);`